# Expanding an array of dictionary pandas

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary

So I have a pandas dataframe with what amounts to an array of dictionaries inside it and I'm struggling with how to turn these into columns that in the original dictionary.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'SomeCol':
                        ["[{'Source': 'A', 'Value': '4.7'}]",
                         "[{'Source': 'A', 'Value': '8.2'},"
                         "{'Source': 'B', 'Value': '100%'}]",
                         "[{'Source': 'A', 'Value': '8.1'}, "
                         "{'Source': 'C', 'Value': '870'},"
                         "{'Source': 'B', 'Value': '98%'}]",
                         "[{}]"
                         ],
                    'Other Stuff': ['One'
                        , 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'
                                    ]
                    })
```

I would like to have the following result

```
    A      B      C
0   4.7     na    na
1   8.2    100%   na
2   8.1     98%   870
```

I have tried

```
data.map(eval).apply(pd.Series)
```

and also numerous variations on the theme

```
def f2(x):
    df_r = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in x:
        df_r = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x, orient='columns')
    return df_r

dfa = pd.concat([df3, df3['SomeCol'].map(eval).apply(f2)])
```

I seem to be missing something important.  The closest I've come is

The result of the first pass of calling the f2 function gets close

```
    Source    Value
0    A        4.7

0    A        8.2
1    B       100%

0    A        8.1
1    C        870
2    B        98%
```

But when I concat them together I get a mess.  Just some help on where to go from here would be helpful.  I've spent the last two days struggling with a simple way as well as a brute force and neigher seems to cut it.

Comment: Solution was simplify, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dictionary with `ast.literal_eval` for convert strings to dicts:

```
import ast

out = [{x.get('Source'):x.get('Value') for x in ast.literal_eval(v)} 
                for k, v in df3.pop('SomeCol').items()]
print (out)
[{'A': '4.7'}, {'A': '8.2', 'B': '100%'}, {'A': '8.1', 'C': '870', 'B': '98%'}, {None: None}]
```

Then pass to `DataFrame` constructor and remove `NaN`s columns by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df3.index).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
print (df)
     A     B    C
0  4.7   NaN  NaN
1  8.2  100%  NaN
2  8.1   98%  870
3  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df3.join(df)
print (df)
  Other Stuff    A     B    C
0         One  4.7   NaN  NaN
1         Two  8.2  100%  NaN
2       Three  8.1   98%  870
3        Four  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Works great.  What's with the .pop.items()?  I don't understand if this is personal preference or if there is some relevance to choosing pop versus just iterating the items in the column?